# How do you obtain the value of the text parameter in a tkinter button widget, and then pass that value as a parameter in the same button?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

How do you obtain the value of the text parameter in a tkinter button widget, and then pass that value as a parameter in the same button?

I want :

```
buttonPCC=tk.Button(poultryImgFrame,text="Chicken Chow Mein",command = lambda addItem("Chicken Chow Mein"))
```

But I was wondering if there was some method of obtaining this text e.g:

```
buttonPCC=tk.Button(poultryImgFrame,text="Chicken Chow Mein",command = lambda addItem(buttonPCC.text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cget` method:

```
buttonPCC = tk.Button(poultryImgFrame, text="Chicken Chow Mein", command=lambda: addItem(buttonPCC.cget('text')))
```